# $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\lambda_{j}a_{j}=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$, where $f(x):=\sum_{\lambda_{j}>x}a_{j}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $a_{j}$ and $\lambda_{j}$ be sequences of positive numbers such that $$\sum a_{j}<\infty;\quad \sum \lambda_{j}a_{j}<\infty.$$

Let $f$ be the function defined by $$f(x):=\sum_{\lambda_{j}>x}a_{j}.$$

**Is it true that**

$$\sum \lambda_{j}a_{j}=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx?$$

It is clear that if $\lambda_{0}=\lambda_{1}=\ldots$ then the statement is true.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\eqalign{ \int_0^\infty f(x)\; dx &= \int_0^\infty \sum_{\lambda_j > x} a_j \;dx\cr
&= \sum_j \int_0^{\lambda_j}a_j \; dx\cr
&= \sum_j a_j \lambda_j}$$

The interchange of sum and integral is justified by Fubini's theorem.